# are {past} if decide to {present}

Tags: grammar, tense

> Things **are blown** out of proportion if you decide to **talk** about it with
> people who are just like you and you **convince** them you are smart.

Not sure, but the tense mismatch sound a little bit off, but I think this is correct. However, I don't remember why this is correct.

Comment: **Blown** in "Things are blown out of proportion" isn't really the *past*, it's a participle in a passive construction.  The things *are* blown out of proportion *by* someone else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is nothing wrong with the tenses.

As written the sentence suggests that you have some repeated experience with that kind of talk. If what you mean is a prediction you should probably say "will be blown out of proportion".

You should write "talk about them" rather than "talk about it" since the things are plural.

I don't understand what you mean by "and you convince them you are smart". Consider editing the question to turn your example into two sentences.